# How does VSCode use JSDoc to generate smart hints?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Does anyone know where I can find where VSCode has all these "hints" about native features in JS so I can do similar things with them?

Notice how it tells me in the image below information about my function. It tells me the parameter in the functions, and a list of options. I'm just wondering where I can find all of this so I can learn from these examples.

Is it somewhere I can download or is it on my device? (I'm on MacOS in case that's important.) Also, is it even JSDoc? (No typescript please: I just don't feel like migrating to it and I don't really like it anyway.)

[image]

Comment: I believe it uses [TypeScript's `lib\dom.d.ts` file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts), but I might be wrong.

Comment: I found an online file: I'll look into it!

Comment: Unfortunately it generates those previews from typescript, not jsdoc (ctrl + click on the `addEventListener` and it'll show you it's location). It uses declaration files to allow these definitions to be added to standard javascript. If you're against coding typescript at all (even declaration files), then the closest you can achieve as far as I'm aware is simply just jsdoc comments (these are also quite good)

Comment: For info on declaration typescript files, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html). You can also see how to mimic typescript features without writing ts code (using jsdoc) [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking)